# Search in populated data in data table even if server side processing is true

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using the below code to populate my data with data table.

```
<html>
<code>
<script>
        var table;
        var gaiSelected =  [];
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
                });

                 $("#uploadIdListTable").dataTable({
                        "bJQueryUI": true
                        });


                   $('#submitDateButton').click(function() {

                       var fromDate=$('#fromdateID').val();
                       var toDate=$('#todateID').val();
                       console.log("todate"+toDate);
                       console.log("fromDate"+fromDate);

                        table = $("#uploadIdListTable").dataTable({
                            "bDestroy": true,
                            "bProcessing": true,
                            "bServerSide": true,
                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                            "sAjaxSource": '/admin/SearchCriteria',
                            "sServerMethod": "POST",
                            "aoColumns": [
                                            { "mDataProp": "uploadId" ,"sWidth": "20%"},
                                            { "mDataProp": "vendorName","sWidth": "10%"},
                                            { "mDataProp": "vendorFeedMedium","sWidth": "10%" },
                                            { "mDataProp": "state","sWidth": "20%"},
                                            { "mDataProp": "filename","sWidth": "30%"},
                                            {
                                                "mDataProp": "vendorId",
                                                "sTitle": "Status Url",
                                                "fnRender": function (o) {
                                                     return '<a href="/admin/uidStatusViewer?uploadId=' + o.aData.uploadId + '">GetStatus </a>';
                                                  }
                                              }
                             ],
                        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                            aoData.push( { "name": "fromDate", "value": fromDate } );
                            aoData.push( { "name": "toDate", "value": toDate } );
                          }
                    });

                   $('#uploadIdListTable tbody tr').live('dblclick', function () {
                         var aData = table.fnGetData( this,0 );
                         alert(aData);
                            });
            });
            });

        </script>
</code>

</html>
```

Problem is, if i use serach it  hits the sever and try to fetch data again. but i want search to be local with the populated data.

is there any parameter available with data table by which i can achieve this?